# VScode cannot use command+click to jump to Vue3's custom component in MacOS

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

For the same project, I can use ctrl+click to jump to the corresponding `.vue` file through the custom component name in Windows 10. However, I cannot use command+click to jump in MacOS. I have tried reinstalling VScode and Open other projects and the problem still exists.I use `unplugin-vue-components` to automatically import components.components.d.ts is generated.The project can run normally.

The display type is displayed when running under the windows version. However, the type of the custom component in mac displays any `.ts` or `.js` function methods and native tags such as `div` can be jumped, but custom components cannot be jumped, such as `el-button`.I also raised the same issue on github https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-vue-components/issues/710 because I don’t have enough reputation to upload pictures.

- VScode version：1.84.0(arm)
- system version：MacOS Ventura 13.6
- unplugin-vue-components: 0.25.1
- TypeScript Vue Plugin (Volar) 1.8.22
- Vue Language Features (Volar) 1.8.22
- PNPM 8.10.2
- Nodejs 20.9.0

Use command + click on MacOS to jump to the `.vue` file of the corresponding custom component.

- tsconfig.app.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["src/types/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

- vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';
import IconsResolver from 'unplugin-icons/resolver';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import Icons from 'unplugin-icons/vite';
import {
  ElementPlusResolver,
  VueUseComponentsResolver
} from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  const isBuild = command === 'build';

  // 读取env配置文件
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());

  return {
    plugins: [
      vue(),
      // api按需导入
      AutoImport({
        // 定义element-plus api按需加载
        resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
        // 导入vue以及其他 api按需加载
        imports: ['vue', 'vue-router', 'pinia'],
        // 目录文件按需加载
        dirs: ['src/enums/**/*', 'src/stores/**/*'],
        vueTemplate: true,
        // 类型文件输出目录
        dts: 'src/types/auto-imports.d.ts'
      }),
      // 自动导入组件
      Components({
        resolvers: [
          // Element plus组件自动导入
          ElementPlusResolver(),
          // Vue组件自动导入
          VueUseComponentsResolver(),
          // 图标自动导入
          IconsResolver({
            prefix: false,
            enabledCollections: ['icon-park-outline'],
            alias: {
              park: 'icon-park-outline'
            }
          })
        ],
        extensions: ['vue', 'ts'],
        dirs: ['src/components', 'src/layouts'],
        // 类型文件输出目录
        dts: 'src/types/components.d.ts'
      }),
      Icons({
        autoInstall: true,
        compiler: 'vue3'
      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
      }
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: '@import "./src/assets/styles/var.scss";'
        }
      }
    },
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: env.VITE_API_URL,
          changeOrigin: true
        },
        '/public': {
          target: env.VITE_API_URL,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
    }
  };
});
```

- tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // 指定全局组件类型
    "types": ["element-plus/global"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you install Volar and Vue Language Features for VSCode?

Comment: @KaiKai Yes I installed it, it was basic so I didn't say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It is a problem with the `Vue Language Features (Volar)` plugin version. Version `1.8.22` has a BUG and cannot display the type of custom components. Just reduce the version to `1.8.11`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a few days ago.

My issue is that the "components.d.ts" and the "auto-imports.d.ds" are not in the "include" field of the tsconfig.json.

Comment: I don’t think there is anything wrong with my configuration, because running the same code in Windows 10 system can jump normally. The following is my `tsconfig.json` configuration file, my `auto-imports.d.ts` and `components.d.ts` are placed in the `src/types` directory. I updated the code for my `tsconfig.json` and `vite.config.ts` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

See [Element Plus docs](https://element-plus.gitee.io/en-US/guide/quickstart.html#volar-support)

> If you use volar, please add the global component type definition to compilerOptions.types in `tsconfig.json`.

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": ["element-plus/global"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have already configured this, but I haven’t posted it yet.

Comment: My project is running normally, but the components cannot jump